# Event.target.value not retrieving value properly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, events

This HTML:

```
<li value="16-May-2017" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.1.2.2.$16">16test</li>
```

I'm trying to retrieve the value of, with this React.js code:

```
  selectDate(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.target.value);
    if(this.state.whichDate == 0) {
      this.state.selectedToDate = event.target.value
      this.state.whichDate = 1
    } else {
      this.state.selectedFromDate = event.target.value
      this.state.whichDate = 0
    }
  }
```

However, I get "16" printed to console instead of "16-May-2017".

I thought it might be printing the text between the tags, but it can't be as I put test there to see... maybe it's not printing anything after the hyphen in the value?

Comment: <li> is not an input element so you cant get its value from .value, you will have to use `.getAttribute('value')`

Comment: .value on an li element has to be a number. Therefore the value attribute is 16: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_li_value.asp

Comment: Not true. I have made `select`s in React with non number values and with `event.target.value` with the `onChange` function of the `select` element. Where are you placing the `onChange` handler?

Comment: You should rather be using a custom data attribute here in the first place, instead of abusing the `value` attribute for something it is not meant for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you want is:

```
console.log(event.target.getAttribute('value'));
```